# How to get offsetWidth of Polymer Component

Tags: polymer-1.0, lifecycle, offsetwidth

I'm trying to get the `offsetWidth` of two custom components inside of another component. Everything I've tried returns a value of 0. The information I need doesn't seem to be ready during the `attached` phase of the life cycle. One approach may be using `iron-resizable-behavior`, but this seems hacky.